# Dynamic casting of object to a type

Tags: java

I've a requirement like, i need to Type cast an object to a dynamic type for the purpose of array addition.

For example :

I'm creating a Float Array Dynamically like this :

```
T array = (T) Array.newInstance(type, length);
```

My item is of double type (value=1.2) and my array is float array.

I need to add items to this array like :

```
Array.set(array, i, value);
```

So what happens is, I'm getting IllegalArgumentException since I'm trying to add double to float array. So I need to type cast it to float before adding. But the issue is the types are dynamic ones like it can be float, int, char, String etc. Please help me with a way to cast and add it to array. Thanks

Comment: is the array type changing or the value type or both?

Comment: @MikedeDood Both can change.... :(

Comment: How do you understand String casting to, say, Double?

Comment: You can go with java generic.

Comment: @user3301492 Actually I'm getting the value from optJson. While watching only I came to know that it is double and at that time my array is float.

Comment: Do you have to end up with the same type array as you start with?

Comment: Why do you want to stuff a bunch of different types into the same array to begin with?

Comment: Your question implies numeric data, whether it is being held in a string or int or double or whatever. Is that true? Or are you dealing with more than just numbers?

Comment: Since your question is obviously not very clear, please take all our questions and edit your question so we all get a clearer picture. That helps us in helping you ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've found a workaround :

```
private Object changeValueToSuitDestType(Object value, Class<?> destType) {
    if (destType == null || value == null) {
        return value;
    }

    String typeString = destType.toString();
    String valueString = value.toString();
    boolean isNull = TextUtils.isEmpty(valueString)
            || valueString.equalsIgnoreCase("null");

    if (typeString.equalsIgnoreCase("boolean")
            || destType == Boolean.class) {
        if (isNull) {
            if (destType == Boolean.class) {
                return null;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            return Boolean.parseBoolean(value.toString());
        }
    } else if (typeString.equalsIgnoreCase("byte")
            || destType == Byte.class) {
        if (isNull) {
            if (destType == Byte.class) {
                return null;
            } else {
                return 0;
            }
        } else {
            return Byte.parseByte(value.toString());
        }
    } else if (typeString.equalsIgnoreCase("short")
            || destType == Short.class) {
        if (isNull) {
            if (destType == Short.class) {
                return null;
            } else {
                return 0;
            }
        } else {
            return Short.parseShort(value.toString());
        }
    } else if (typeString.equalsIgnoreCase("int")
            || destType == Integer.class) {
        if (isNull) {
            if (destType == Integer.class) {
                return null;
            } else {
                return 0;
            }
        } else {
            return Integer.parseInt(value.toString());
        }
    } else if (typeString.equalsIgnoreCase("long")
            || destType == Long.class) {
        if (isNull) {
            if (destType == Long.class) {
                return null;
            } else {
                return 0L;
            }
        } else {
            return Long.parseLong(value.toString());
        }
    } else if (typeString.equalsIgnoreCase("float")
            || destType == Float.class) {
        if (isNull) {
            if (destType == Float.class) {
                return null;
            } else {
                return 0F;
            }
        } else {
            return Float.parseFloat(value.toString());
        }
    } else if (typeString.equalsIgnoreCase("double")
            || destType == Double.class) {
        if (isNull) {
            if (destType == Double.class) {
                return null;
            } else {
                return 0D;
            }
        } else {
            return Double.parseDouble(value.toString());
        }
    } else if (typeString.equalsIgnoreCase("char")
            || destType == Character.class) {
        if (isNull) {
            if (destType == Character.class) {
                return null;
            } else {
                return '\u0000';
            }
        } else {
            return value.toString().charAt(0);
        }
    } else if (destType == String.class) {
        if (isNull) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return value.toString();
        }
    }

    return value;
}
```

Thanks to all for your valuable answer and for me I find like there is no other easy way for this. If you guys find something like this, please let me know. Once again thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that there is a well-considered reason why the data type of the item is double. Instead of trying to cast the double to a float (which may lead to serious errors) I suggest to change the type of the array to `Double`.

Comment: I cannot change the type of array to double since its type is determined dynamically. So based on that I need to cast the value that I'm getting..

Answer (score 0):

As specified in the [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html), all `java.lang.Number`s can cast themselves to any other numeric type. Such as

```
(new Double(3.5d)).floatValue()
```

As far as your array, you must obviously choose a single type for it, and then cast all values to that type as required. You cannot create an array of a generic type, as you have discovered. However, you can dynamically figure out the array type you need and create it:

```
public class ArrayOfType  {
   public static final void <N extends Number> N[] get(N number, int length)  {
      if(number.class.isAssignableFrom(Integer.class))  {
          return  new Integer[length];
      else if...
```

Use it with:

```
T[] arrayOfT = ArrayOfType.<T>get(someNumOfTypeT, 3);
```

Comment: I'm not known of the type of array and the type of value that I'm having. Its all dynamic ones.

Comment: Ultimately, you must know what type of array you are dealing with. You simply cannot create an array of a generic type, except indirectly as I mention in my answer. Perhaps your array should be an array of `Number`s?

Comment: Also, once you determine what type the array must be, you must explicitly cast all potential elements to that type, whether it's a string (which you'll have to parse and crash if its invalid), or convert with the `Number.*Value()` functions.

Answer (score 0):

One possible fix:

```
Array.set(array, i, (T) value);
```

because all you want to do is cast the `value` to become type `T` that the array has already been defined as. Of course this is just a generic answer that will work most of the time, but you have to be carefull when converting from one data type to another.

Also if you use aliteralmind's answer:

```
Array.set(array, i, value.floatValue());
```

assuming that `value` is a type that extends `Number`.

Comment: In your first example, if `value` is a `String` and you attempt to cast it to a `double`, program crashes. In your second example, if `value` is a `String` and you attempt to call `floatValue()`, program crashes.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose `Double` -> `Float` conversion is the first problem you encountered. You will probably need type conversion mechanism implemented on top of your code. I.e.

```
interface TypeConverter<T> {
    T convertTo(Class<T> clazz, Object value);
}
```

Then you create registry with all converter implementations you need and use them based on target class (Array item class).

```
class FloatTypeConverter implements TypeConverter<Float> {
    @Override
    public Float convertTo(Class<Float> clazz, Object value) {
        if (value instanceof Float) {
            return (Float) value;
        } else if (value instanceof Double) {
            return new Float(((Double) value).floatValue());
        } else {
            throw new UnsupportedConversion();
        }
    }
}
TypeConverterRegistry.register(Float.class, new FloatTypeConverter());
...

TypeConverter<?> converter = TypeConverterRegistry.getConverterFor(type);
Array.set(array, i, converter.convertTo(type, value));
```

Comment: The `Number`s interface provides converter functions to all other numeric types: `num.intValue()`, `num.floatValue()`, ...

Comment: I assume he will need conversions from/to other types too. Also he does not know if the type is Number - his system is dynamic, thus type is unknown.